# How to insert text and html within a tag where the text appears first and html appears second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking on the internet, but I failed to find the correct solution.

What I have here erases the text content with the html, and I need both there.

On the markup I need something like this:

```
<h1 class="stock-count">54<span class="stock-count-info">In Stock</span></h1>
```

But I keep getting something this (without 54):

```
<h1 class="stock-count"><span class="stock-count-info">In Stock</span></h1>
```

This is the jQuery code I have tried:

```
$(".stock-count").text(count);
$(".stock-count").html("<span class='stock-count-info'></span>");
$(".stock-count-info").text("In Stock");
```

Has anyone got any suggestions?

PS. The span tag HAS to be within the h1 tag.

Comment: Just do it all in one with a concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You can add count and `stock-count-info` span directly to html of `stock-count` span in a single call.

```
$(".stock-count").html(count+"<span class='stock-count-info'>In Stock</span>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.append()`:

```
$(".stock-count").append("<span class='stock-count-info'>In Stock</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `prepend` to insert the element before

```
$(".stock-count").html("<span class='stock-count-info'></span>").prepend(count);
```